# C++ no equal sign but compiles without assigning value

Tags: c++

While tracking down a bug in my software, I encountered a weird behavior, and was wondering if anyone would have some hindsight.

Here is the code (it compiles and does not have any runtime errors):

```
#define ERR_OK 0
#define ERR_NOT_OK -41

int some_class::some_function(uint32_t verbose){
    int ret_value = ERR_OK;

    if (some_condition) {
         ret_value ERR_NOT_OK;
    }

    return ret_value;
}
```

Why does this line compile; it's missing an equal sign:

```
ret_value ERR_NOT_OK;
```

Xcodebuild log:

```
CompileC /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/some_class.o api/src/some_class.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/project_name_dev
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wassign-enum -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -fasm-blocks -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -iquote /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/project_nameAPI-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/project_nameAPI-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/project_nameAPI-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/project_nameAPI-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/DerivedSources/include -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/DerivedSources -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unknown-warning-option -F/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Products/Debug -Wall -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/some_class.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/some_class.dia -c /Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/project_name_dev/api/src/some_class.cpp -o /Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jal-emkfpcfmbsgbyrammutcuwrgpqox/Build/Intermediates/project_name.build/Debug/project_nameAPI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/some_class.o
```

Edit: Removed semicolons and changed #define ERR_NOT_OK 1 to #define ERR_NOT_OK -41; added xcodebuild log.

Comment: What toolchain?

Comment: VS2013 won't compile it.

Comment: Are these your real definitions of `ERR_OK` and `ERR_NOT_OK`? E.g. do you really have those `;` in the replacement text? Also, what compiler did you use to compile this?

Comment: At best will, your [stuff doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5467bc7362160b60).

Comment: Are you sure you're not just running an executable that no longer matches the source?

Comment: First never put semicolon at the end of macro. Second - never use macro to define constants in C++.

Comment: @Slava The semicolon is a typo.

Comment: @AnT ERR_NOT_OK is actually -41

Comment: @Matt I am running this on the latest OSX toolchain.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Definitely compiles or I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Onep: If `ERR_NOT_OK` is actually `-41`, why did you provide a misleading definition of `ERR_NOT_OK` in your question? It is a critical detail.

Comment: @AnT explain why it is such a critical detail? Please

Comment: @Onep: Your question is about why the code compiles. However, the code you provided originally could not possibly compile in any credible compiler. This made it into a nonsensical question.

Comment: @Ant I just compiled it again, I added the log from xcodebuild.

Comment: @Onep: So? Of course it compiles now, in its proper form with accurate definitions for your macros. My answer below already explained that. But your question in its *original* form with fake macro definitions was non-compilable and thus misleading and self-contradictory .

Comment: @AnT I did some more testing and I believe the answer is a bit more complicated. I tried compiling code with "ret_value -41;" and the compiler yells at me. I am using LLVM though, so my bet is that the preprocessor might actually be doing more than just a simple replacement.

Comment: @Onep: What exactly does your compiler tell you in response to `ret_value -41;`?

Comment: @Ant Expression result unused.

Comment: @Onep: That's a genuine "warning", i.e. not an "error". I.e. the code is perfectly legal from the language point of view and should compile successfully. Are you saying that in your original code this warning is not issued? In any case, whether you'll see this warning depends on the compiler settings.

Comment: Yes no warning in original code. Thanks.

Comment: @Onep: Well, apparently there's some other difference between original and non-original code (and, possibly, compilation settings) that prevents this warning from appearing. GCC, for example, does not emit it by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ERR_NOT_OK` is defined as `-41`, then your

```
ret_value ERR_NOT_OK;
```

is substituted with

```
ret_value -41;
```

which is a valid expression statement, even though it is effectively a no-op. What was originally intended as unary `-` gets interpreted as binary `-` in this context.

This is why it is a good idea to define it as

```
#define ERR_NOT_OK (-41)
```

Comment: This compiles with llvm, I did not think this was a valid expression.

Comment: yet another reason not to use macro for constants

Comment: @Slava: Yes, but if constants are in a header intended to be usable in both C and C++ code, then you don't have much of a choice. It is either macros or enums.